# Unable to get system beep to work in C using various methods

Tags: c, beep

I have tried \a \7 the windows.h beep function etc etc and nothing works.

Does newer hardware not have this functionality built in?

(Console Program)

Comment: Is this a console program or a Windows program?

Comment: Sorry I should have said, it's a console program.

Comment: \a works just fine for me on Windows 7. You might have to be more specific.

Comment: You might like to read the page at ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277%28VS.85%29.aspx ). Apparently, if I interpret it right, there is no way to beep in Windows. Maybe you can do `MessageBeep(0xFFFFFFFF);` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, printf("\a") should generate an alarm. To the best of my knowledge, this is done through the PC speaker. In modern systems, there is no hardware PC speaker. It's sometimes emulated by your soundcard, but that's OS and driver specific. In short, you might be out of luck.

You can try MessageBeep(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680356(VS.85).aspx.

Good luck.

Also, you should check all the usual culprits like your sound card being muted, speakers plugged/not plugged in, etc.

Comment: printf("\a") does work in my case, but only when the volume is not muted. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 3):

Newer hardware is required to have a beep for people with disabilities, but Windows 7 moved the `Beep()` into the actual Windows Audio Subsystem (so make sure your speakers are turned on). Larry Osterman explains it all on his blog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

First open a CMD prompt and type:

echo ^V^G    <-- this is control-V control-G

If you don't hear the beep, something is misconfigured or missing.

Answer (score -2):

You can do Beep(frequency, duration) and you get a beep that follows that frequency. The frequency limit is 37-32767 hertz. The duration is measured in milliseconds and has no limit.
For example:

```
Beep(1000,3600);
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail? What API is this a part of? What header file needs to be included?

Comment: The header file needed for Beep() method is windows.h.

Comment: It appears this was addressed in the original question and isn't a usable solution.

Comment: What do you mean it is not a usable solution. You could use Beep(int) in the question it said beep(int) didn't work, but later on Joe Scho says he was on mute. It should work if your machine is not on mute. Also if your frequency is a certain amount the sound of the beep will change. If it is too low you wont here it and if its to high you won't here it either. Trust me I have used Beep(int) method before, it works. If you don't believe me go on MSDN and look up Beep() method.